# Blackscreen after changing systemctl

Tags: boot, mint

I wanted to start my linux mint laptop in terminal mode, so I searched the internet and found this command: `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

After running that command and rebooting, it started normally but ended in a black screen. It looks like it turned off my screen and I could not enter a boot menu. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot into [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). That will get you to a root shell prompt.
2. At the prompt:

   ```
    # systemctl set-default graphical.target`
    # systemctl reboot
   ```